# Multi label learning using Sci Kit Learn Random forest

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have gotten this code learning each label by specifying the individual label column, now I'm trying to get all labels specified simultaneously...
The data is in a Pandas dataFrame. When I train on each label I get et better than 73% on each label. I do want to train for each label independently. So maybe this is the wrong approach altogether?

This version seems to be just training on one label in the list or maybe it is training them all and I don't know how to properly introspect?

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
#split the dataset for train and test
combnum['is_train'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, len(combnum)) <= .75
train, test = combnum[combnum['is_train']==True], combnum[combnum['is_train']==False]

et = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=114, max_depth=None, min_samples_split=10, random_state=0  )

labels = train[list(label_columns)].values 
#I get good results with 
#labels = train["service_a"].values

features = train[list(columns)].values

et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels, n_jobs=-1).mean()

print("{0} -> ET: {1})".format(columns[1:2], et_score))
```

which outputs: ['n_0003'] -> ET: 0.282943628784)
label_columns is just a list of column headers eg:

```
['service_a',
 'service_b',
 'service_c',
 'service_d',
 'service_e',
 'service_f',
 'service_g',
 'service_h',
 'service_i',
 'service_j',
 'service_k',
 'service_l',
 'service_m',
 'service_n']
```

which is derived the same way as the features list (which works...)
I'll be wanting to get cross validation scores by label, can that be done?

When I change the last two lines to:

```
et_score = cross_val_score(et, features, labels, n_jobs=-1)
print("{0} -> ET: {1})".format(label_columns, et_score))
```

I get::  ['service_a', 'service_b', 'service_c', 'service_d', 'service_e', 'service_f', 'service_g', 'service_h', 'service_i', 'service_j', 'service_k', 'service_l', 'service_m', 'service_n'] -> ET: [ 0.28435115  0.28633761  0.28033815])

Comment: RF supports multi-label classification, by training your model for each class you essentially create N models which are only good for classifiyng that specific class, there should be no need to separate the data in this way, RF can handle multi-label's fine. The issue will be whether you have sufficient data for each label to train and also if your features are sufficient to distinguish each class

Comment: So.. specifically what have I done wrong? I fed RF a list of labels and a list of features?